# partition of unity \ multiplication in sobolev?

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness, sobolev-spaces, smooth-functions, support-function

*let $\Omega$=$\omega_1$ × $\omega_2$

q1:
why for any open set $ω'_1$ satisfying  $ω'_1$ ⊂⊂ $ω_1$ , we can find an other open set $ω''_1$ such that
$ω'_1$ ⊂⊂ $ω''_1$ ⊂⊂ $ω_1$
and a smooth function ρ satisfies suppρ ⊂ $ω''_1$  , ρ = 1 on $ω'_1$

q2:
if $u_\varepsilon$ and $u_0$ are in $H_0^1(\Omega )$
why
$({u_\varepsilon } - {u_0}){\rho ^2} \in H_0^1(\Omega )$ ?

Comment: 1) the closure of $\omega'$ is compact and then has a positive distance to the complement of $\omega$, 2) why not?

Comment: thank you @daw,

for q2, sorry, i added now  $\Omega$=$\omega_1$ × $\omega_2$

i want to know how it is in $H_0^1(\Omega )$